# Angular - Google Cloud Run - Deploy Port issue

Tags: angular, docker, google-cloud-run

I am having a couple of problems running my container

Steps:> ng build --watch

This is ok

build image > docker build -t pblah-angular -f nginx.prod.dockerfile .

This is also ok

run container >  docker run -d -p 8080:80 pblah-angular

This is serving the page, but not making the backend call, as it is not using the port of backend server. This is the problem

I have `proxy.conf.json` with target something like `localhost:9001`
and start `npm start` which uses `"start": "ng serve --disable-host-check --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

This works well, as this is not container

But How can I tell docker run also to use the proxy conf?

**Second Problem**: I deployed to Google cloud, and it fails with below error. I am not using any variable. what is PORT issue there? How to deploy angular to Cloud Run

Ready condition status changed to False for Revision pblah-00002-gov with message: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

**New Updates:**
I used npm start to test the frontend. It used the proxy.conf.json via package.json 's start command --proxy-config

So it worked

Now I created container and running on nginx
I was in the illusion that it was working...tried lots of things docker-compose etc...or overlooked thinking 8080 is working than 4200

A little research told me that I need to do something in nginx.config

So updated dockerfile to have that extra CMD(the last one)

```
RUN npm run build -- --prod

##### Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
# VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=node /app/dist/pyui /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY proxy.conf.json /etc/nginx/conf.d/

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and updated nginx.config with upstream section and the /server section. Still not working "locally", If workes, I will then update for cloudrun

```
    upstream springboot
    {
        server localhost:9001  max_conns=10;
    }

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    256M;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /server {
        proxy_pass http://springboot;
          proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      }
}
```

Comment: Which port is your application configured to listen to? Which port is configured for your Cloud Run service? Cloud Run is not Docker. Docker specific commands and configurations do not apply to Cloud Run. Edit your question: show your code, Dockerfile, deployment command and error message.

Comment: Cloud Run can listen, and expose only one port. If you try to expose the 9001 and the 8080, it will fail. Can you describe more precisely what do you want to set up in Cloud Run?